# Highlight a word input fields in a table of crosswords puzzle js/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image: crossword puzzle]

```js
$(".clues_container_h").append("<div class='enuns'><p id='enunH-" + i + "'>" + i + enun_h_arr[i] + "</p></div>");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
//part of the table:

<table id="navigate" class="tblnavigate">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="numbers"></td>
      <td class="numbers">1</td>
      <td class="numbers">2</td>
      <td class="numbers">3</td>
      <td class="numbers">4</td>
      <td class="numbers">5</td>
      <td class="numbers">6</td>
      <td class="numbers">7</td>
      <td class="numbers">8</td>
      <td class="numbers">9</td>
      <td class="numbers">10</td>
      <td class="numbers">11</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="numbers">1</td>
      <td><input id="cell-0" autocomplete="off" name="cell-0" onkeypress='validate(event)' type="text" maxlength="1"></td>
      <td><input id="cell-1" autocomplete="off" name="cell-1" onkeypress='validate(event)' type="text" maxlength="1"></td>
      <td><input id="cell-2" autocomplete="off" name="cell-2" onkeypress='validate(event)' type="text" maxlength="1"></td>
      <td><input id="cell-3" autocomplete="off" name="cell-3" onkeypress='validate(event)' type="text" maxlength="1"></td>
      <td><input id="cell-4" autocomplete="off" name="cell-4" onkeypress='validate(event)' type="text" maxlength="1"></td>
      <td><input id="cell-5" autocomplete="off" name="cell-5" onkeypress='validate(event)' type="text" maxlength="1"></td>
      <td><input id="cell-6" autocomplete="off" name="cell-6" onkeypress='validate(event)' type="text" maxlength="1"></td>
      <td><input id="cell-7" autocomplete="off" name="cell-7" onkeypress='validate(event)' type="text" maxlength="1"></td>
      <td><input id="cell-8" autocomplete="off" name="cell-8" onkeypress='validate(event)' type="text" maxlength="1"></td>
      <td><input id="cell-9" autocomplete="off" name="cell-9" onkeypress='validate(event)' type="text" maxlength="1"></td>
      <td><input id="cell-10" autocomplete="off" name="cell-10" onkeypress='validate(event)' type="text" maxlength="1"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

If i click on any input (square) all the inputs (that belongs to the word) would change background color. How can i achieve this?